# Django sites framework country separation

Tags: django, internationalization, country, sites

I'm developing a web site with Django where we list products and some comments for them. I'd like to have separate sites for each country with different product objects. For example:

us.domain.com - products in U.S are listed and the page is English.

fr.domain.com - products in France are listed and the page is in French etc.

1) What came to my mind is to alter settings.SITE_ID depending on the subdomain requested in a middleware, but this is said to be dangerous. What else can I do? I don't want to run separate instances or settings.py file for each country.

My solution so far:

```
class SubdomainMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        host = request.META.get('HTTP_HOST', '')
        try:
            site = Site.objects.get(domain=host)
        except:
            site = Site.objects.get(domain='www.domain.com')
        request.site = site

products = Product.objects.filter(site_id=request.site)
```

Here, below doesn't work because CurrentSiteManager uses settings.SITE_ID, not the request.site:

```
on_site = CurrentSiteManager()

Product.on_site.all()
```

I have to explicitly pass site_id=request.site at each query. Is this safe, or are there any other alternatives?

2) If I add site = models.ForeignKey(Site) field to the Product model, is it enough? Or should I add that field to all other models like Comment, etc.?

Comment: Hint: instead of multiple domains which is not great for SEO, you could use Django's new [localized url feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-url-patterns). You can easily set request.site in a middleware btw **do set it as a request attribute** because it is thread safe.

Comment: It's great to know request.site is thread-safe. Thanks! But regarding URLs, Google is said to change its strategy to support subdomains (http://www.whitefireseo.com/site-architecture/subdomain-or-subfolder-post-panda/360/)